# Android App with NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js

I am investigating developing an app for Android that will be self-encapsulated (no outside requests) that can work offline.  I'm very fond of NodeJs and web technologies, and was wondering if there's a way to use NodeJs as a "server side" for an application that uses something like phonegap or Cordova for UI.  The application will need to provide functionality of sqllite database requests and multiple views.

Is there any framework/solution for something like this?  If not, would a view management component framework like angularjs work? Or am I better off just writing my application in Java?

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you want to use Cordova/Phonegap anyway, which part of your app requires node.js?

Comment: @still_learning database connection, asset management/loading.

Comment: node.js can be run on android.  There are many articles on that topic if you do a Google search.  I think folks are not clear on why you want to do that, but you can.

Comment: I just created a question on a number of alternatives I found: [Compiling NodeJS as native library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459909/8295283)